# In flutter, I need the prayer times schedule notifications but it is not working, using awesome notifications and i don't have error message

Tags: flutter, dart, awesome-notifications

notification page class

I use awesomenotification package and this is class

I made class for check permission and create notifications services

and show notifications function

```
class NotificationService {
  static Future<void> initializeNotification() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null,
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelGroupKey: 'high_importance_channel',
          channelKey: 'high_importance_channel',
          channelName: 'Basic notifications',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
          defaultColor: const Color(0xFF9D50DD),
          ledColor: Colors.white,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          channelShowBadge: true,
          onlyAlertOnce: true,
          playSound: true,
          criticalAlerts: true,
        )
      ],
      channelGroups: [
        NotificationChannelGroup(
          channelGroupKey: 'high_importance_channel_group',
          channelGroupName: 'Group 1',
        )
      ],
      debug: true,
    );

    await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then(
      (isAllowed) async {
        if (!isAllowed) {
          await AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
        }
      },
    );

    await AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
      onActionReceivedMethod: onActionReceivedMethod,
      onNotificationCreatedMethod: onNotificationCreatedMethod,
      onNotificationDisplayedMethod: onNotificationDisplayedMethod,
      onDismissActionReceivedMethod: onDismissActionReceivedMethod,
    );
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when a new notification or a schedule is created
  static Future<void> onNotificationCreatedMethod(
      ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    debugPrint('onNotificationCreatedMethod');
  }

  /// Use this method to detect every time that a new notification is displayed
  static Future<void> onNotificationDisplayedMethod(
      ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    debugPrint('onNotificationDisplayedMethod');
  }

  /// Use this method to detect if the user dismissed a notification
  static Future<void> onDismissActionReceivedMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    debugPrint('onDismissActionReceivedMethod');
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when the user taps on a notification or action button
  static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    debugPrint('onActionReceivedMethod');
    final payload = receivedAction.payload ?? {};
    if (payload["navigate"] == "true") {
      MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => const Salah(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  static Future<void> showNotification({
    required final String title,
    required final String body,
    int? hour,
    int? minute,
    int? day,
    int? month,
    int? year,
  }) async {
    Random random = Random();

    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          id: random.nextInt(1000) + 1,
          channelKey: 'high_importance_channel',
          title: title,
          body: body,
          actionType: actionType,
          notificationLayout: notificationLayout,
          summary: summary,
          category: category,
          payload: payload,
        ),
        actionButtons: actionButtons,
        schedule: NotificationCalendar(
          hour: hour,
          minute: minute,
          day: day,
          month: month,
          year: year,
          allowWhileIdle: true,
          timeZone: await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier(),
          repeats: true,
        ));
  }
}
```

location and notification class

in this class i get latitude and longitude to pass them for adhan package to return time for each prayer time

```
class location extends StatefulWidget {
  const location({super.key});

  @override
  State<location> createState() => _locationState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _locationState extends State<location> {
  String _fullAddress = "اضغط هنا لتحديد الموقع الحالي";
  double _latitude = 0.0;
  double _longitude = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _schedulePrayerNotifications();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _schedulePrayerNotifications() async {
    final myCoordinates = Coordinates(
        _latitude, _longitude); // Replace with your own location lat, lng.
    final params = CalculationMethod.egyptian.getParameters();
    params.madhab = Madhab.shafi;
    final prayerTimes = PrayerTimes.today(myCoordinates, params);

    await NotificationService.showNotification(
      title: "صلاة الفجر",
      body: "حان الوقت الأن لأداء صلاة الفجر بتوقيت $_fullAddress",
      payload: {"navigate": "true"},
      hour: prayerTimes.fajr.hour,
      minute: prayerTimes.fajr.minute,
      day: prayerTimes.fajr.day,
      month: prayerTimes.fajr.month,
      year: prayerTimes.fajr.year,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

i see an issue while you are calling **_schedulePrayerNotifications**. let's try this below code, i hope it will save your times.

```
Future<void> _schedulePrayerNotifications(double latitude, double longitude) async {
  final myCoordinates = Coordinates(latitude, longitude); // Replace with actual coordinates.
  final params = CalculationMethod.egyptian.getParameters();
  params.madhab = Madhab.shafi;
  final prayerTimes = PrayerTimes.today(myCoordinates, params);

  // Replace the missing arguments with appropriate values.
  await NotificationService.showNotification(
    title: "صلاة الفجر",
    body: "حان الوقت الأن لأداء صلاة الفجر بتوقيت $_fullAddress",
    actionType: ActionType.defaultType,
    notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
    summary: 'summary',
    category: 'category',
    payload: {"navigate": "true"},
    actionButtons: [],
    hour: prayerTimes.fajr.hour,
    minute: prayerTimes.fajr.minute,
    day: prayerTimes.fajr.day,
    month: prayerTimes.fajr.month,
    year: prayerTimes.fajr.year,
  );
}
```

Comment: I will try, Can you help me check how much time remains for the message to be displayed so that I know whether it will arrive on time or not instead of waiting for the next prayer time?

Comment: I have this message in the debug console 
/Android: [Awesome Notifications](11267): Date is not more valid. (2023-10-01 20:51:33 UTC) (NotificationScheduler:201)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications](11267): Scheduled removed (NotificationScheduler:249)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications](11267): Notification schedule removed in 39ms (NotificationScheduler:258)
D/Android: [Awesome Notifications](11267): Date is not more valid. (2023-10-01 20:51:33 UTC) (NotificationScheduler:201)